# I am curious about the algorithmic technique to sort large amounts of data. ( Not quick sort and merge sort)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Assuming you have 1 billion data on your website and only show 100 of those data in the most recent order, which algorithm is best for you, except for quicksort and merge sort?

Quick Sort and Merge Sort are (1billion)log(1billion)

Is there any algorithm with faster time complexity than this?

Comment: Can't you just keep track of the 100 most recent items as they come in?

Comment: Why would you sort this much data? You could use a cache for this, or keep the order of insertion in your database

Comment: There is no need to sort it at all; by definition, the 100 most recent items are the last 100 that were added.

Comment: If you need the 100 most *extreme* values then use quickselect to find them in linear time, and then sort them however you like.

Comment: If there is underlying order, but not necessarily sorted order, in the data then you might look into translating that order into your sorted order. This un-shuffling might be quicker than a dumb sort.
Timsort for example, used in Python and now in Java as the default sort makes use of the observation that most data to be sorted has *regions* of local sorted order.

Comment: Not really active since 2019, since maintainer died at sea, but: http://sortbenchmark.org/

Comment: To follow up, a lot of those competitors in the bencmark have custom hardware/software solutions for the specific task of sorting. Note, this is the key takeaway, hardware is just as if not more important than software when looking to optimize a specific task. There are examples of this all over in other domains. For example ASICs for bit-coin mining and Tensor Cores for deep learning shenanigans.

Comment: Add a time value to every item as they come in. Then use priority queue of atmost size as 100, to keep a track of only the most recent 100 items.